# How far is R to creating more fluent looking web maps?

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

I was wondering how close is R is to creating web maps like [this one, below](http://clhenrick.github.io/greenpoint_williamsburg_toxicity_map/).

[image]

***I'm particularly interested in with the sidebar appearance and functionality.*** I figured there has to be some sort of progress, given Leaflet functionality already exists in R. The best I've seen out of R is utilizing Shiny for these kinds of dynamic functionalities, but Shiny server need not be run for maps like this, which are dynamic due to JavaScript.

Are we far from creating a map like this one, or not? If so, can anyone explain why? If not, are there any kinds of R mapping examples (*code available?*) one an share? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at http://rmaps.github.io/?